# My rigid body animation freezes after second frame

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

My animation records frames but the rigid bodies don't work after the second frame. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you baked your animation or are you using the live calculation?

Comment: I've tried both.